# Django functions definition in views.py not shown in coverage?

Tags: python, django, python-coverage

I am using coverage in the following way to test my django app:

```
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$(SETTINGS) coverage run manage.py test -v 2
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$(SETTINGS) coverage report
```

In my test suite I tests some views:

```
class TestJSON(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client.login(username='admin', password='passwordz')

    def test_bookmarks_json(self):
        translator = User.objects.create_user('normaluser', 'foobar@test.com',
                                              'secretz')
        search = SearchBookmark(
            search="minutes")
        search.save()
        response = self.client.get('/bookmarks_json/')
        ans = json.loads(response.content)[0]
        self.assertEqual(...)
```

So I am clearly hitting everything defined in that view for `'/bookmarks_json/'`. Never the less `coverage report` says that the signature line is not hit, e.g.:

```
@login_required
def bookmarks_as_json(request):
    bookmarks = SearchBookmark.objects.all()
    data = serializers.serialize("json", bookmarks)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

I have seen the solution by Ned Batchelder here [Django coverage test for URLs 0%, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899439/django-coverage-test-for-urls-0-why) and I am guessing it is some how related. 
As a result I wrote my own test runner:

```
import os
import sys
import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.test.utils import get_runner

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings.dev'
    django.setup()
    TestRunner = get_runner(settings)
    test_runner = TestRunner(verbosity=2)
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(["myapp.tests"])
    sys.exit(bool(failures))
```

And

```
   python testrunner.py   # works, def in view.py is reported !
```

However, I would like to use the normal command `./manage.py test` so I was wondering if there is a way to fix this, with out writing my own test runner.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue with your test seems to be that you do not log in before testing the view. Since the view uses the `login_required` decorator, the client is redirected, the view doesn't run, so it will show as missing in the coverage report.

You can log in using `self.client.login()` before your `self.client.get()` call.

```
translator = User.objects.create_user('normaluser', 'foobar@test.com',
                                      'secretz')
search = SearchBookmark(
    search="minutes")
search.save()
self.client.login(username='normaluser', password='secretz')
response = self.client.get('/bookmarks_json/')
ans = json.loads(response.content)[0]
```

Comment: That is not the issue. What you don't see, is that my `setUp` method does the login. I'm also checking that the content delivered is fine.

Comment: OK, you didn't show your setUp method at first, so we couldn't see that you had logged in. I'll delete this answer now.